# Select distinct join multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have two long tables in MySQL that has the form of the following

```
Tab1
=========
col1 col2
A    X
B    Y
```

And

```
Tab2
=========
col3 col4
A    dog
A    cat
A    dog
B    tree
B    tree
B    bush
```

I'd like to retrieve for each row of Tab1 the distinct values of Tab2 where col1=col3, such that the output looks something like

```
   Col1   Col4
    A    (dog,cat)
    B    (tree,bush)
```

I tried with combination of `SELECT DISTINCT` and `JOIN ON` but I just obtain

```
dog
cat
tree
bush
```

Is what I'd like to do feasible?

Comment: Tab2 isn't a table in a strict rdbms sense, because it has no unique key. Can you address that issue somehow? Otherwise, this isn't really an sql problem

Comment: The original Tab2 has also a 3 column that is set as primary key where all the values are different from each other

Comment: Read up on group_concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: show the query, you are writing to fetch the desired result???

Comment: adding the previous suggestion: select col3 group_concat(distinct col4 ) from Tab2 join Tab1 on Tab1.col1=Tab2.col3; but I can see that it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Tab1.col1, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Tab2.col4) 
FROM Tab1 
INNER JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.col1 = Tab2.col3
GROUP BY Tab1.col1
```

Be aware that "*The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024*". (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

You should set this variable to a higher value if you are expecting lots of concatenated values.

Comment: In this way I only obtain the first row that is A (dog,cat) but not B (tree,bush)

Comment: My bad: I forgot the GROUP BY! I've edited my answer with the correction.

Comment: As this is an inner join, tab1 is redundant.